# CSS text layout issue

Tags: html, css

I am using alertify to display notification on my application, The text in success notification is wrap and in multiple lines but I want it on one single line?

How do I do it?

I am not able to add link to CodePen in question hence added it in comment,
Please check live demo.

Click on "Success notification" button you will get the popup and in that popup the text is is in multiline but I want it in single line.

Comment: Code Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwvwyZ

Comment: Change the `width: 300px;` of `.alertify-logs` to whatever you like.

Comment: Is it possible to adjust it according to text length? I don't want to give any hard coded width.

Comment: Yes. Change it to `width: auto` like Zabusy answered already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.alertify-logs {
position: fixed;
z-index: 5000;
bottom: 10px;
right: 10px;
width: auto; 
}
```

I changed `width: 300px;`to `width: auto;`. It's on single line.
Is that what you wanted, correct? It also auto adjusts to whatever lenght of your text is/will be.